# Arguments to bind

Tags: c++

A practice question on **c++ primer**：Use *bind* and *check_size* to find the first element in a *vector* of *ints* that has a value greater than the length of a specified *string* value.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

bool check_size(const string& s, string::size_type sz)
{
    return s.size() < sz;
}

int main()
{
    string word("turtle");
    vector<int> ivec{ 1,2,4,6,3,7,5,8 };
    sort(ivec.begin(), ivec.end());
    auto it = find_if(ivec.cbegin(), ivec.cend(), bind(check_size, word, _1));
    if (it != ivec.end())
        cout << *it << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles and outputs as expected.But I am very confused, what is the parameter passed to the placeholder _1?

Comment: The first (and only) parameter passed by `find_if` is the current item.

Comment: But the actual parameters are not explicitly passed in the program.

Comment: What do you mean? `std::find_if` passes it.

Comment: A lambda would have been much clearer. That `bind` expression is roughly equivalent to `[word](string::size_type sz) { return check_size(word, sz); }`. That is, `bind` expression manufactures an object that is callable with one parameter. `find_if` calls that object, passing elements of the range to that sole parameter.

Comment: @gaofeng - std::bind was designed at a time when lambdas were not yet available. If you don't know all things about bind, just leave it at that and use lambdas instead for new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the parameter passed to the placeholder _1?

The *argument* passed to the placeholder parameter `_1` is a reference to the element(s) in the range `[first, last)` which is `[ivec.cbegin(), ivec.cend())` for your example.
This argument(which is the current item in the range) is **implicitly** passed by the `find_if` algorithm to the callable generated from  `bind(check_size, word, _1)` along with `check_size` and `word`.